# I am creating a Api using java JpaRepository I need to put a variable in the query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to get all the products in my product table by category. But I don't want to write out the query string for all my categories. I want to instead create a variable that can be passed in through my mapping . The only way I found to do that is through JPLQ I am using MySQL and I want to know how to turn JPLQ syntax into native queries.

product repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import tts.backend.dashboardapi.model.Product;

import java.awt.print.Pageable;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {

    @Query("select u from products u where u.category = :category")
     List<Product> findByCategory(@Param("category") Integer category);

    @Query("select u from products u where u.category = :category AND u.availability = :availability")
    List<Product> findByCategoryAndAvailability(@Param("category") Integer category,
                                               @Param("availability")Boolean availability);
```

product controller

```
  @GetMapping("/product/{category}")
    public List<Product> findByCategory(@RequestParam (value= "category")Integer category){
        return productrepository.findByCategory(category);
    }
```

product model

```
package tts.backend.dashboardapi.model;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class Product  implements  Serializable{
    public Product() {
    }
    public Product(Integer id, String productName,Category category, double fullPrice, double salePrice, boolean availability, Supplier supplier){
        this.id = id;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.category = category;
        this.fullPrice = fullPrice;
        this.availablity = availability;
        this.supplier = supplier;

    }



    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;


    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name= "category")
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "full_price")
    private double fullPrice;

    @Column(name = "sale_price")
    private double salePrice;

    @Column(name = "availability")
    private boolean availablity;


    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier")
    private  Supplier supplier;
```

I only had the mapping for one of my queries because I got a bunch of exceptions when running my program.

Comment: Could you edit and add your Product model too?

Comment: Those repo method appear to be [JPA parseable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details), why is the @Query needed?

Comment: It is not necessary add the annotation `@Query(....)`  since Spring JPA provides `Supported query keywords` you should just remove them and combine the query keywords on the methods https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords in you case you should put `findByCategory(Integer category)` only

Comment: @JonathanJohx when I do what you suggested I get this error when I test it  "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/api/category/1'

Comment: so you want to change above queries to native queries? @Rashsmit

Comment: "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/api/category/1'"  means that you have another method in the controller, whose mapping also matches the url /api/category/1.  You'll have to remove one